# Table refuses to forget cell formula which once overrode a column formula

Tags: org-mode

The following is very simple org-mode spreadsheet in which the cells in the second column show the triple of the corresponding cell in the first column due to the "column formula" in its TBLFM row `$2=3*$1;N`.  However the third row (actually row @4) is an exception because of the "cell formula" `@4$2=string("Exception")` which expectedly overrides the above column formula.

```
|--------+-----------|
| Number |    Triple |
|--------+-----------|
|      1 |         3 |
|      2 |         6 |
|      3 | Exception |
|      4 |        12 |
|--------+-----------|
#+TBLFM: $2=3*$1::@4$2=string("Exception")
```

So all is well.  Below you will find a copy of the above table, except that, after copying, I have deleted the exceptional formula affecting cell @4$2.

```
|--------+-----------|
| Number |    Triple |
|--------+-----------|
|      1 |         3 |
|      2 |         6 |
|      3 | Exception |
|      4 |        12 |
|--------+-----------|
#+TBLFM: $2=3*$1
```

One would expect that, after updating this table with `C-u C-c *`, or `C-c C-c` in the TBLFM line, the exceptional value in cell @4$2 would revert to the triple of '3', but instead the string "Exception" stays put.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I noticed that if I save the file, close it (kill-buffer) and then reopen it, the strange behaviour disapears, namely, updating the table with `C-u C-c *` causes cell @4$2 to turn to '9', as expected.

I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 and the latest version of org-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The persistence of the string `exception` has nothing to do with copying.
If you recalculate the original table and afterwards remove the field formula from it you also have the problem that `exception` is not replaced by `9` at the next recalculation.

The reason for that behavior is that the text property `:org-untouchable` is put on the output of field formulas. The normal function of `:org-untouchable` is to prevent the modification of cells with field formulas during the evaluation of a column formulas.

In my opinion the `:org-untouchable` property should be removed at the beginning of calls to `org-table-iterate` and at the beginning of interactive calls of `org-table-recalculate`.

You can obtain this behavior with the advices below.
These advices are tested with `org-version` `9.0.5` in emacs 25.1.50.2.

I would agree that the original behavior is faulty. Therefore, I suggest to file a bug-report at https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode.
A proper bug-fix should probably be implemented differently.

```el
(defun org-table-remove-untouchable (&rest _args)
  "Remove `:org-untouchable' property from org-table."
  (save-excursion
    (cl-assert (org-at-table-p) nil "Not in org-table.")
    (remove-text-properties (org-table-begin) (org-table-end) '(:org-untouchable nil))))

(defun org-table-recalculate-remove-untouchable (&optional all _noalign)
  "Remove `:org-untouchable' property at the beginning of `org-table-iterate'.
Use this function as :before advice of `org-table-iterate'."
  (when (and (called-interactively-p 'any)
         all)
    (org-table-remove-untouchable)))

(advice-add 'org-table-iterate :before #'org-table-remove-untouchable)
(advice-add 'org-table-recalculate :before #'org-table-recalculate-remove-untouchable)
```

Comment: Hi @Tobias,  thanks very much for your clarification!  I will file the bug report as you suggest.

Comment: My impression is that the implementation of cell-formulas within column-formulas by means of messing with properties is a bad ideal.  It would be much better to treat these exceptional formulas by themselves, perhaps after all column formulas are applied, updating the cell entries in the usual way.

Comment: The bug report was filed and it has been fixed by Nicolas Goaziou (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-11/msg00183.html).  Nicolas also explained to me the purpose of using text properties to deal with cell-formulas within columns affected by  column-formulas and I am now convinced that this if indeed a good way to proceed, contrary to my first impression above.